# Why should I buy the brand solar panels when the cheaper ones offer a better power to price ratio?

Tags: solar-power

Following [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/solar/comments/lffr9f/does_it_worth_paying_50_more_for_25_more_power/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I'm trying to figure out what is [the best](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VoUsAAXXXFm3Erhn0beJWxM2p9iHrHYsYQAyv_PsfCg/edit?usp=sharing) option for me.

Looking at brand products, for example SunPower Maxeon 3 400/410 Wp and SunPower P3 Black 325 Wp, they offer a power to price ratio of almost 1.1-2.1, while Jinko Tiger JKM355M-6TL3-V offers 3.2 (both in € here in the Netherlands). Now my question is that why should I choose SunPower over Jinko? Is it because of the reliability and durability, or are there other hidden aspects of the brand products that could make them a cost-effective option? In simple terms, which one is a better investment?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because of the reliability and durability,

Indirectly, yes. It's partly about the duration of the warranty and your confidence that the manufacturer will still be around to replace defective panels in ten years time. Or twenty years time. There's a bit of [a rant here](https://www.solarquotes.com.au/blog/solar-panel-warranty-paradox/) about why the actual length is possibly not worth bothering about: decent panels won't fail; decent companies go bust anyway; you're going to forget you *have* the warranty (or not measure the performance); and panel prices are (currently) dropping so replacements will be cheap (and likely more efficient). But... you can't get decent panels with short warranties so it's not necessarily useful to apporach things that way.

The other part is the "does what it says" warranty. Some countries have decent consumer protection laws (Australia, for example) and oddly a lot of those cheap panels aren't sold in Australia, only in China and the USA. I've never tested the cheap panels, but the mere fact that no-one is willing to import them and sell them here is very suggestive to me.

I have talked to one person with a pair of "500W" panels that are huge but apparently he was given them free by whoever bought them direct from China because the actual output was similar to the 200W panels they replaced. So not worth the hassle of having giant panels in a space that would fit four or more actual 200W panels.

In Australia we also had a pile of panels fail due to water ingress, and at least some of that was due to [cheap backing material](https://www.ecogeneration.com.au/solar-pv-module-backsheet-durability-an-issue-for-australia/) but much was just poor construction or damage during installation (microcracks aren't necessarily easily visible, you just have to handle panels carefully).

Answer (score -1):

SunPower is the high end of module manufacturers with a high per per square meter ratio.  The main reasons to choose SunPower over a lower cost tier 1v manufacturer is limited roof space and you want the most output in that space or astetics, SunPower modules are sleek.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Are you affiliated with SunPower by any chance? Your post reads a bit as if it's spam. We require posts to mention any affiliation of recommended products.